# java regex get value after specific value

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, endpoint

I have some endpoints that contains `/bot/{idBot}`, i need to extract that `idBot`.

Can we do it via regex in the java ?

here are some examples of endpoints:

```
/bot/6/block/30/content/text
/bot/6/block/content/input/list/option/30
/account/bot/32/language
/account/bot/6
```

tried with that with no sucess!

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("/bot/(\\d+)").matcher(path);
```

Edit: I have some endpoints like this:

```
/account/checkToken
/account/checkUser
```

those need to be ignored!

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String#replaceAll` for a regex one-liner option:

```java
String input = "/account/bot/32/language";
String num = input.matches(".*/bot/\\d+.*") ? input.replaceAll(".*/bot/(\\d+).*", "$1") : "";
System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: thanks worked!!! but humm i forgot to the that i can have others endpoint like this ... /account/checkToken for example, and this give me error.

Comment: @sealabr Then use `String#matches` with a ternary expression to assign empty string in the case that `/bot/` does not appear within the input.

Answer (score 2):

matcher.group(1) is what you are looking for.

Look at the full code below.

**Sample Code :**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\/bot\\/(\\d+)";
final String string = "/bot/6/block/30/content/text\n"
     + "/bot/6/block/content/input/list/option/30\n"
     + "/account/bot/32/language\n"
     + "/account/bot/6";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("Required match: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output :**

```
Full match: /bot/6
Required match: 6
Full match: /bot/6
Required match: 6
Full match: /bot/32
Required match: 32
Full match: /bot/6
Required match: 6
```

**EDIT : To support excluding some APIs, updated regex**

Added negative lookahead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "^(?!\\/account\\/checkToken)(?!\\/account\\/checkUser).*\\/bot\\/(\\d+)";
    final String string = "/bot/6/block/30/content/text\n"
            + "/bot/6/block/content/input/list/option/30\n"
            + "/account/bot/32/language\n"
            + "/account/bot/6\n"
            + "/account/checkToken/bot/6\n"
            + "/account/checkUser/bot/78";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println("Required match: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Full match: /bot/6
Required match: 6
Full match: /bot/6
Required match: 6
Full match: /account/bot/32
Required match: 32
Full match: /account/bot/6
Required match: 6
```